# How do I update the Chart.js automatically every 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would like to display a chart on a website that updates automatically every 2 seconds.

I don't know JavaScript very well yet. I found and tried this example: 
https://blog.heimetli.ch/chart-js-update.html

```
var getData = $.getJSON('/value');
getData.done(function (result) {

  var zeit = result.zeit;
  var flow = result.flow;
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: zeit,
      datasets: [
        {
          data: flow,
          label: "Flow>",
          borderColor: "#0004cd",
          fill: false
        },
      ]
    }
  });
});
```

Unfortunately I have not yet managed to change my code from the example (link) so that it works in my code. What do I have to do?

I want my code updated automatically every 2 seconds. Thanks for your time:)

Comment: use polling or websocket

Comment: yes that's an idea to improve. But I want to run it like this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very practical (but not that efficient) solution would be JavaScript's `setInterval()`.

Here is an example:

```
setInterval(function() {
    let getData = $.getJSON('/value');
    getData.done(function(result) {

        var zeit = result.zeit;
        var flow = result.flow;
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: zeit,
                datasets: [{
                    data: flow,
                    label: "Flow>",
                    borderColor: "#0004cd",
                    fill: false
                }, ]
            }
        });
    });
}, 2000) // 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
```

This will get the information from the source you provide trough AJAX and will execute the same code you are using for your first render after every request.

The issue with this method would be that every time you update your chart, it will generate a request to the server you specified.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. i've already tried your idea. that works so well. but now the chart.js doesn't seem liquid. i have to work with these functions.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html 
yes you're right it would be better if i use a Web-socket. but i want to solve it now so that every time a request is made.